# using php code within html to dynamically load a dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to use php code within html to grab content from a database to populate the values for a drop down menu (see below).  When I run the php script on its own (test.php) I get all the expected values.  When nested within html I get nothing but a single blank value under Select a Species.  I would expect this to run through the while loop more than once as there are about 7 values returned and I would also expect the contents to include data derived from the table.

What I am attempting is possible correct??
Is it just an error with code (no errors popping up in the logs)

```
<label for="select">Species Observed : </label>
<select name="select" class="textfields" id="species">
    <option id = "0">-- Select a Species -- </option>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx","databases");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bc_species WHERE 1"); 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     ?>
     <option><?php echo $row['species'];?></option> 
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: whats that `json_encode` for? just echo it combining the markup option

Comment: check where 1 in this SELECT * FROM bc_species WHERE 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <option><?php echo $row["species"]; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
        $optionData = '<option id = "0">-- Select a Species -- </option>';

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx","databases");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bc_species WHERE 1"); 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $optionData .= "<option>".$row['species']."</option>" ;
        } 
?>
<label for="select">Species Observed : </label>
<select name="select" class="textfields" id="species">
    <?php echo $optionData;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Put your fetched data on an array then loop them like this

```
<?php 
                        foreach ($list as $data  => $item) {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $data?>">
                            <?php echo $data?>
                        </option>
                   <?php
                        }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<label for="select">Species Observed : </label>
<select name="select" class="textfields" id="species">
    <option id = "0">-- Select a Species -- </option>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxxx","databases");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bc_species"); 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
           echo '<option>'. $row["species"].'</option> 
     } ?>
</select>
```

You were not iterating through the values within the HTML `<option>` tags, so I moved those into the while loop. (notice the PHP section includes echoing those tags).

I also removed the unnecessary "SQL injection-looking" `where 1` clause from your query.